# what is the specific term for this implementation?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the specific name for this so I can look up some information on how it's done. If you have used Evernote's application on Android, they have this icon on the bottom right which slides up several options when it is pressed. It can be seen [here](http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/android-animation-2.gif)

I'm on the android developer site and can't seem to find anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is called a ["Floating Action Button"](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#) from Google's material design. Android has an [example project](https://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html) for it.

Comment: Nice answer,@tommy-magnusson. Adam, The generic term for this is progressive disclosure—providing "more" when the user needs it.